# How create one-to-zero-or-one with IdentityUser?

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, asp.net-identity

I have my class

```
public class Person
{
   public string Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Age {get;set;}

   public virtual Patient {get;set;}
   public virtual User {get;set;}
}
public class Patient 
{
   public string PersonId { get; set; }

   public string Address1 { get; set; }
   public string Address2 { get; set; }
   public string City { get; set; }
   public int Zipcode { get; set; }
   public string State { get; set; }
   public string Country { get; set; }

   public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class User : IdentityUser
{
}
```

I want to create One-Zero-Or-One mapping in `Patient.cs` and `User.cs` with `Person.cs`

For my `Patient` class in use this `FluentApi`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasOptional(p => p.Patient).WithRequired(p => p.Person);
```

And to my User class, how should I do?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want Patient and User to reference an optional Person object. Is this correct?

Comment: @StevenManuel Yes, is optional